# some problems with dplyr and full join option

Tags: r, dplyr

I would join some table with diplyr but it reminds me some errors.

I have two variables and i want to join them, but it reminds me some errors.  What is wrong? How can create a table using dplyr that make the correct match between rows? Thank you

```
Mouth_tissues= counts_sample_mouth0$counts
Glands= counts_sample_gland0$counts  

head(Mouth_tissues)
  Mouth_tissues
gene0                                                                              547
gene1                                                                               78
gene2                                                                                5
gene3                                                                               13
gene4                                                                               16
gene5                                                                               49
> head(Glands)
  Glands
gene0                                                                                                 332
gene1                                                                                                  60
gene2                                                                                                 583
gene3                                                                                                6964
gene4                                                                                                2162
gene5                                                                                   6
> full_join(Mouth_tissues, Glands)
Error in UseMethod("full_join") : 
no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class   "c('matrix', 'integer', 'numeric')"
```

Then I did:

```
 mouth<-as.data.frame.matrix(Mouth_tissues)

 glands<-as.data.frame.matrix(Glands)
library(dplyr)

full_join(mouth, glands)
Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace




dput(head(counts_sample_gland0))

dput(head(counts_sample_mouth0))
```

Comment: Both objects need to be data frames for `full_join` to work. If `class()` of `Mouth_tissues`, and `Glands` are not `data.frame` the join won't work.

Comment: Ok. thank you. How can transform them into data frames?

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(head(counts_sample_gland0))` and `dput(head(counts_sample_mouth0))` to your question please?

Comment: ok! I did it...

Comment: No, I mean the *output* of those two lines if you paste them into your R shell. The R output will look something like `structure(list(...`

Comment: `as.data.frame(data)` will transform your data

Comment: I converted into data frames but it reminds     "Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables"
 What is by = ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do?

Have joined both tables using a full join on the 'Num' column.

```
library(tidyverse)

MouthTissue=c("gene0","gene1")
Num=c(547,78)
Mouthtissues_df=data.frame(MouthTissue,Num)

Glands=c("gene0","gene1")
Num=c(332,60)
Glands_df=data.frame(Glands,Num)

fulljoin=dplyr::full_join(Glands_df,Mouthtissues_df)
```

Comment: the problem is that I have 28000 genes

Comment: Whether you have two rows of data or 28K, it should work the same way.